# Finding the Fourier series of $\delta(x)$ on $ (-\pi, \pi)$ (dirac delta)

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, dirac-delta

So $\delta(x)$ is even, so it will be a cosine series.
I get to 
$$a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\delta(x)cos(nx)dx $$
for $a_0$ I get $\frac{1}{\pi}$. Now there's the following property of the delta function:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-a)f(x)dx = f(a)$$
Can I apply that property, where $a=0$, and there's an $n$ in $\cos(nx)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$a_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\delta(x)\cos(nx)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)f(x)dx$$
where $f(x)=\cos(nx)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{[-\pi,\pi]}(x)$ where $\mathbf{1}_{[-\pi,\pi]}$ is the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what $I(x)$ is here?

Comment: @RonaldB See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you apply $a = 0$ it looks like you just get $a_n = 1$.

The resulting series would just be $1+\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \cos{nx}$

I graphed a few partial sums on Mathematica and they look pretty interesting.

Here's 5 terms:

[image: Partial Sum of Fourier Series for Delta function, 5 terms]

Here's 10 terms:

[image: Partial Sum of Fourier Series for Delta function, 10 terms]

Here's 20 terms:

[image: Partial Sum of Fourier Series for Delta function, 20 terms]

The graphs do appear to be converging on an impulse at the origin, with periodic impulses at intervals of $2\pi$.

I should note that the series itself appears to diverge, which means all those wiggly bits at to the left and right of the impulse (where the original function is zero) grow without bound as more terms are added on.